# How to bisect right a pandas time series from a starting date

Tags: python, pandas

assume that you have a `pd.Series` such has:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-10')
df = pd.Series(1, index=dates)
```

I would like to bisect it from '2019-01-01' but excluding it from the index so the result looks like

```
2019-01-02    1
2019-01-03    1
2019-01-04    1
2019-01-05    1
2019-01-06    1
2019-01-07    1
2019-01-08    1
2019-01-09    1
2019-01-10    1
```

my solution seems dirty.

```
df = df['2019-01-01':]
df = df.loc[df.index != '2019-01-01']
```

Comment: `df[df.index > '2019-01-01']`?

Comment: @QuangHoang ouch... yes that's what I need.